# How do i make my website available in the Google PlayStore and AppStore?

Tags: android, swift

If i create a website, and i want it to be available in a form of an app for both android and ios users. Do i need to learn swift and android development to achieve this or there’s an easy option to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ***Hybrid*** platform to develop that App. One platform to develop and then distribute. Like React Native etc.,

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to learn these languages for this task. Just download Android sdk and run this below code by replacing your website URL with "www.example.com" for creating android app for your website and same thing you can do for iOS. This code will create simple webview application for your website:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:id="@+id/webView"  
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />  

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.webview;  

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.webkit.WebView;  

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        WebView mywebview = findViewById(R.id.webView);  
        mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/");   
    }  
}
```